# On click Javascript transform

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, click

I am trying to achieve a flip card effect on the click of a button but I can not quite figure out the Javascript. I actually know nothing about Javascript so I have attempted to find similar solutions and alter them to my needs but with no results. Below is the CSS for how it is now as a `:hover` style.

You can view it here : http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/290-2

**CSS:**

```
.flip3D { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 675px;
    }

.flip3D .front {
    position: absolute;
    -o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;

}

.flip3D .back {
    position: absolute;
    -o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg );
    transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: -o-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -moz-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -ms-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;
}

.flip3D:hover > .front {
    -o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg );
    transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( -180deg );

}

.flip3D:hover > .back  {
    -o-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );
    transform: perspective(600px)RotateY( 0deg );

}
```

And I have buttons with classes `.flip-button` for the front and `.flip-back` for the back.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Dan

Comment: Post your relevant HTML and Javascript here also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [plugin](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/). It may helps you. And here there is a list of plugin that do flip effect: http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-flip-effect-plugins/

**Edited**

This may helps you! I only toggle the class `.flip` in `.front` and `.back` . (http://jsfiddle.net/0x13mL26/3/)

Sorry for the misunderstanding! :)

Comment: Thank you for tip on using a plugin. I have tried a few plugins to achieve this but couldn't get the results I wanted which is why I am trying to do it without a plugin. Plus it a great way for me to expand my knowledge.

Comment: You want to do it as your own! ;), this is a good iniative, I like it! :)

Comment: Ok this is great.... It is working brilliantly, and I can see and understand how it all works now. Just need to experiment a bit now but this is a great starting point. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you! :) would you mark it has resolved? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for javascript, but my solution is with JQuery. Use a click function on each button and then you can use Jquery's .removeClass and .addClass methods to change the class of the card that needs to be flipped when the button is being clicked. Something like this should work:

```
$( "#frontbutton" ).click(function() {

    $("#flipcard").addClass('back');
    $("#flipcard").removeClass('front');
    $("#frontbutton").css("display","none");
    $("#backbutton").css("display","static");

});


$( "#backbutton2" ).click(function() {

    $("#flipcard").addClass('front');
    $("#flipcard").removeClass('back');
    $("#backbutton").css("display","none");
    $("#frontbutton").css("display","static");

});
```

and of course you will want to hide the "backbutton" initially.

So when you click the front button, it will change the class of the "flipcard" you have making it flip. The "frontbutton" will then hide, and in its place you put the now visible "backbutton". When the back button is clicked, it should trigger the same process but opposite.

Comment: Hi there,  Thank you for this. I have tried experimenting with it but unfortunately I can not get it work. But I will keep experimenting.